# Arima model with only summer months (how to set up arima model)

Tags: time-series, arima

all

My data set only has summer months data from May to September from 2005 to 2013.
So, basically, my data set looks like this.

May 1st, 2005: 80
May 2nd, 2005: 84
...
Sep. 30th, 2005: 80
May 1st, 2006: 80
May 2nd, 2006: 83
...
Sep. 30th, 2007: 80

So, I am saying my data set is somewhat discontinuous. In this case, Could any of you guys let me know how to set up ARIMA models?

Thank you in advance.